# Two definitions of cotangent complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

I have reading a paper by Professor Pridham(https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4044v4). Page 47-48 contains a comparison of the two definitions of the cotangent complex, but there is a part I don't understand.

In detail, Prop 7.21 on page 48 says $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}_{\mathscr{X}/\mathscr{Y}}$ is the sheafification of $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}$.

**Question1**
What is the definition of “sheafification” written in the previous sentence.

And, I have one more question.

**Question2**
Does the last sentence on page 47 means the same as the statement of the proposition ?

I would appreciate if anyone who knows can tell me.　I am also very grateful for the comments.

Thank you !

Comment: 1) Sheafification of that presheaf in the etale topos $X_{\bullet,et}$ from section 4 of the Olsson paper cited there, i.e. taking the sheaf associated to that presheaf.

Comment: 2) No - if you look at the first line of the proof, you will see that the expression there is not the same as the formula at the end of p47, so the purpose of the proof is to show that they are quasi-isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.                                                                                                             (1): to me, $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}$ seems a chain complex, but how should I sheafify $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}$ ?

Comment: (2):So what does “ sheafification ”  in the last sentence of page 47 mean?

Comment: In terms of the terminology on p29 of Olsson's paper, I meant any (quasi-coherent) complex on $X_{\bullet,et}$ whose restriction to $X_n$ is quasi-isomorphic $(\mathbb{L}^{X/Y})^n$.

Comment: That means $\mathbb{L}^{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}_{X/Y}$ is quasi-isomorphic to $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y} $?

Comment: Yes, though they live in slightly different categories iirc.

Comment: What you said is that $\mathbb{L}_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}$ in the Olsson paper is in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathcal{X})$, but  the associated complex of  $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}$ is in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{X})$ ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply many times.  But, to me, it seems that $u^*N^s\Omega(\^{X}/Y)$ in $\mathbb{L}^{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}_{X/Y}$ and $u^* \Omega(\^{X}/Y)$ in $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y} $ are different although I thought $\mathbb{L}^{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}_{X/Y}$ is quasi-isomorphic to $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y} $.

Comment: Something's not rendering in your comment, but the answer might be that normalised and unnormalised chains are quasi-isomorphic. See for instance the simplicial sections of Weibel's homological algebra.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. Thank you for giving me the reference. And, what is the definition of Tot ? It seems that the complexes are not double complexes.

Comment: When Tot's applied it is to a double complex, the two directions coming from the simplicial and cosimplicial structures.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood. After all, are the definitions of cotangent complex by Olsson and by Toën-Vezzosi same ? To me, it seems that the former is in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{X})’$ while the latter is in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{X})$.

Comment: What is the definition of “sheafification”  in the last sentence on p47 ?

Comment: The quasi-coherent complex of sheaves associated to that $O(X)$-module.

Comment: That means $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}$ in Olsson paper(the formula (8.2.3)) is different from $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}$ in the paper in general?

Comment: I think the issue's just $O(X)$-modules versus $\mathcal{O}_{X,et}$-modules, so they're the same for practical purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to me that “sheafification” of Prop 7.21 does not make sense if $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}$ and $\mathbb{L}^{X/Y}$ are  $N^sO(X)$-modules. I am a little confused.

Comment: In the prop, is $ \mathbb{L}^{X/Y}_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}}$ regarded as a $\mathcal{O}_{X,et}$-module ?

Comment: that's my recollection

Comment: Thank you very much. So, does “sheafification ” in the prop also mean the chain complexes of $\mathcal{O}_{X, et}$-modules associated to $N^sO(X)$-modules ? I am sorry for asking the same questions.